# What are the column-like beams on Portal 2 called?

Tags: portal-2

What is the real name of the column-like beams in Portal 2 called? They are only (as far as I know) referred to as "beams" (By Wheatley: "I'll turn the beam off."). Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image: Beam-like thing]

Comment: It's also referred to by Wheatley as a funnel: "Cubes, buttons, funnels...it's got it all."

Comment: I demand a spoiler alert on the potato.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a Tractor beam made of liquid asbestos called an [Aperture Science Excursion Funnel](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Excursion_Funnel)

[image]

Comment: It's an **Aperture Science** Excursion Funnel. Not using the proper title could get you sued or referred to the Aperture Science Non-Cooperative Testing Program.

Comment: It's also referred to as "Tractor beams", That's why Wheathly mentions the word "beam".